# FMUL does not clear overflow in STATUS register

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, x87

I have this Win32 code:

```
fld x
fmul y
fstsw ax
```

It seems that `fmul` does not clear FPU status registers bit, i.e. if overflow was already set (`ax` & 8) then it will stay set after `fmul`. Is it the correct behavior? Is it required to clear status after or before FPU operations?

I.e. I suppose `fmul` will set this bit, but should it reset it? I could not find the answer online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You bet it is correct behavior.

From `8.1.3.3 x87 FPU Floating-Point Exception Flags` of `Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual`, volume 1:

> The exception flags are “sticky” bits (once set, they remain set until explicitly cleared). They can be cleared by executing the FCLEX/FNCLEX (clear exceptions) instructions, by reinitializing the x87 FPU with the FINIT/FNINIT or FSAVE/FNSAVE instructions, or by overwriting the flags with an FRSTOR or FLDENV instruction.

It is not required to reset these flags if FPU exceptions are disabled.

Comment: OK thanks. I found FNCLEX in some functions but not in others, that helped to see the problem.